# How to get count in single row?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I am just trying to get knowledge on mysql

```
 mysql> SELECT species, sex, COUNT(*) FROM pet
        -> WHERE species = 'dog' OR species = 'cat'
        -> GROUP BY species, sex;

+---------+------+----------+
| species | sex  | COUNT(*) |
+---------+------+----------+
| cat     | f    |        1 |
| cat     | m    |        1 |
| dog     | f    |        1 |
| dog     | m    |        2 |
+---------+------+----------+
```

Is it possible to get?

```
+---------+-----------+-------------+
| species | malecount | femalecount |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
| cat     | 1         |       1     |
| dog     | 1         |       2     |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

In single query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to *pivot* the data from rows into columns:

```
select species,
  sum(case when sex = 'm' then 1 else 0 end) maleCount,
  sum(case when sex = 'f' then 1 else 0 end) femaleCount
from pet
group by species
```

Answer (score 8):

This is the shortest possible answer in `MySQL`.

```
SELECT  species,
        SUM(sex = 'm') maleCount,
        SUM(sex = 'f') femaleCount
FROM    pet
GROUP   BY species
```

MySQL also supports inline `IF` statement:

```
SELECT  species,
        SUM(IF(sex = 'm',1,0)) maleCount,
        SUM(IF(sex = 'f',1,0)) femaleCount
FROM    pet
GROUP   BY species
```

---

You can also use `CASE` which works on almost RDBMS:

```
SELECT  species,
        SUM(CASE WHEN sex = 'm' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) maleCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN sex = 'f' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) femaleCount
FROM    pet
GROUP   BY species
```

Comment: you can choose any queries you like `:)` but since you tagged with `MySQL`, I'd rather use the summation of boolean result.